# PHP Modules not matching with PHP Info file

Tags: php-ini, php, bcmath

So I am trying to install the bcmath module and it seems to have worked but when I check my phpinfo it says it is not on there.

This is the output I get when I do `php -m`

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Not sure if this makes a different but I am using nginx and CentOS and I also used the command `yum install php74-php-bcmath.x86_64` to install it. Here is a screenshot of where the bcmath module should be in my phpinfo:
[image]

Comment: php has multiple .ini files, typically one for cli, one for apache-webserver and possibly one for php-fpm.  Make certain they are running the same version, and that that the configs are correct.

Comment: Also, after installing a module you might need to restart Nginx